Bind CSS with knockout Secure Bindings
How Can I bind CSS to a div using knock out secure bindings.
The following piece of code is not working.
data-sbind="css:{'has-error': isNullOrWhiteSpace($root.UserID()) == true,'MandatoryFields':isNullOrWhiteSpace($root.UserID()) == false}"

var koOptions = {
            attribute: "data-sbind",        // default "data-sbind"
            globals: window,               // default {}
            bindings: ko.bindingHandlers,  // default 
               ko.bindingHandlers
            noVirtualElements: true      // default true
        };
        ko.bindingProvider.instance = new ko.secureBindingsProvider(koOptions);

    if (isBound(UI.MainContainer) == false) {
        //ko.bindingProvider.instance = new ko.secureBindingsProvider(self, $('#' + UI.MainContainer, '#' + UI.AppContainer)[0]);
        ko.applyBindings(self, $('#' + UI.MainContainer, '#' + UI.AppContainer)[0]);
    }

The has-error class is not binding.
I am getting the following error
at
: 
38
message
: 
"Expected ')' but got '$'"
name
: 
"SyntaxError"
text
: 
"css:{'has-error': isNullOrWhiteSpace($root.UserID()) == true,'MandatoryFields':isNullOrWhiteSpace($root.UserID()) == false}"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object


Where is the func isNullOrWhiteSpace defined? show the func and provide more deatails.
BTW, is "data-sbind" misspelled?

The documentation for knockout secure binding mentions they only support a subset of javascript, and "functions do not accept arguments.". So my guess is that after isNullOrWhiteSpace( it just wants to see a ).

I'd suggest adding additional computed values to your viewmodel instead. E.g. self.hasError = ko.pureComputed(() => isNullOrWhiteSpace(self.UserId()) and then doing css: { 'has-error': $root.hasError }
